# How do I make an argument optional if a condition is met?

Tags: python, command-line-arguments

I'm just starting out with [docopt](http://docopt.org/), and with it I am trying to write an usage command that will accept one or more optional arguments if the command matches something. Here it is at its current state:

```
Usage:
  script.py voucher (add|del) <code> <credits> [<points>]
```

Here, first the `voucher` command is used, and then either `add` or `del`. I want to change the line so that if `add` is used, both the `code` and `credits` arguments are required, but `points` is optional.

However, if `del` is used instead, then only the `code` argument is needed.

How would I be able to do this?

Comment: I'm not really familiar with docopt, but I would expect `script.py voucher (add <code> <credits> [<points>] | del <code>)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
"""S.O. 12766628

Usage:
    script.py voucher add <code> <credits> [<points>]
    script.py voucher del <code>
"""
from docopt import docopt


if __name__ == '__main__':
    arguments = docopt(__doc__, version='S.O. 12766628')
    print(arguments)
```

Does what you need.